# How to install Selenium IDE in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: selenium, firefox-addon, selenium-ide

I tried to install Selenium IDE in Firefox but unable to install. Please help me. My Firefox version: 47.0.2 while install IDE button is disabled please help me.

[image]

Comment: the error is self explanatory.

Comment: image view added

Comment: Related pages: https://seleniumhq.wordpress.com/2017/08/09/firefox-55-and-selenium-ide/ https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/selenium-developers/MtlQATQ9a5I

Comment: It happened due to version incompatibility of FF and Selenium IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to restart as suggested in your screenshot. If that doesn't helps, install the latest version of firefox in your computer.

Also, in case, if you require how to do so, following link provides detailed steps to download and install selenium ide.

[Link providing detailed steps to download and install selenium webdriver](https://www.guru99.com/install-selenuim-ide.html)

Comment: well, try installing older versions which might support it.

Answer (score 0):

Below are shared steps to Download and Install selenium IDE for Firefox browsers. Make sure to install the latest version of Selenium IDE with an updated version of Mozilla Firefox.

**1.** Launch the Mozilla Firefox browser.

**2.** Open URL **https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/selenium-ide/**
It will redirect you to the official add-on page of Firefox

**3.** Click on the "Add to Firefox" button.
[Add to Firefox button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tbk9m.png)

**4.** A pop-up dialog box will be appeared asking you to add Selenium IDE as an extension to your Firefox browser.

**5.** Click on the "Add" button.
[Dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCQUT.png)

**6.** Restart the Firefox browser.

**7.** Go to the top right corner of your Firefox browser and look for the Selenium IDE icon.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jfYl.png)

**8.** Click on that icon to launch Selenium IDE.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nocdk.png)